# Вывести количество вхождений в строчке без учета регистра

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(LENGTH(`title_prev`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`title_prev`, '".($l = 'a|d')."', ''))) / LENGTH('{$l}') `cnt`
```

В 8 версии mysql, появилась `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Как в моем случае её верно заменить, так чтобы как и прежняя cnt - выводила количество вхождений в строчке без учета регистра?

Comment: *без учета регистра* - укажите явно требуемый COLLATION.

Comment: Можно пример? Что та подсказывает, что это немного не то

Comment: (LENGTH(`title_prev`) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(`title_prev`, 'Главное|d', 'i'))) / LENGTH('Главное|d')

Comment: Вроде работает, а вроде на половину. В строке присутствует слово 'главное' и 3 'd'.  Регистр не учитывается, ок. Но в подсчете выдает не 4, а 1.085. Если искать только 'главное' - тут сразу указываем верный регистр. То все равно выдает не целое число, а 0.095. Почему?

Comment: Потому что изменение длины при замене не должно зависеть от того, какой паттерн найден.

Comment: А если искать по одному символу, скажем по 'd'.  То подсчет будет равен нулю и так же по 2 - 3 сивола, если они раздельно. Везде будет 0

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример, а запутался во всем этом. Не выходит

Comment: Чтобы посчитать количество вхождений, надо разницу длин с заменой и без поделить на разницу длин, когда замена строго одна.